# Trying to get div content to show upon clicking with jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Having trouble getting content to show upon clicking a link with jQuery. all the CSS and Code is in there for right now. I just want it to simply pop up once you click on "Antonio Nogueras". CSS is at the bottom. Let me know what I can do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Glotacosm - Digital Production - SEO/PPC/SOCIAL/COPYWRITING/DESIGN/WEBDESIGN</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.ready(function() 
    {
        $('div#about').click(function() {
        $('div#aboutcontent').show();
    });
    });
    </script>
<body>

<h1>GLOTACOSM -SEO/PPC/SOCIAL/COPYWRITING/DESIGN/WEBDESIGN </h1>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="MainMenu">
    <div id="about">
        <a class="change" target="_blank" >ANTONIO NOGUERAS</a></br>
    </div>
        <a class="change" target="_blank" id="digitalmarketing" >DIGITAL MARKETING</br>
        <a class="change" target="_blank" >SOCIAL MEDIA MGMT</br>
        <a class="change" target="_blank">FORMS + FUNCTIONS</br>
        <a class="change" target="_blank">A WAY WITH WORDS</br>
        <a class="change" target="_blank">WEB DEVELOPMENT</br>
        <a class="change" target="_blank">GENERAL MUSINGS</br>
    </div>
<div class="aboutcontent">
    <div class="profilepic">
        <img src="http://square205.com/images/the-team/Antonio-photo1.jpg"></img>
        <p>
        Name: Antonio Nogueras</br>
        Age: 24</br>
        Stomping grounds: Denton, TX</br>
        Height: Astronomical</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
        <p id="p1about">
                <p>To indtroduce myself, my name is Antonio Nogueras and I'm somewhat of a digital ventrlioquist - I make the pixels do the talking for me. I do a lot; you may have noticed. Let me be upfront so as to be clear: all of who I am does not come without the profficiency and efficiency of ideas. It is my honor to weild a world of language, code and color to bring digital clairvoyance to the electro-landscape of the 21st century.I have been writing almost all my life, and typos, like nagging gremlins, claw at my integrity each day, but what doesn't kill you surely makes you stronger. I have also been in tune with the underpinnings of the digital marketing landscape for some time now, </ br>    
                </br>
                </br>
                Now, where were we? Oh, that's right - I'd like to work for you, or you simply just peruse my expertise. Let's talk business or shop, or maybe we can talk about how to implementing a how to fine-tune your web shop for a more fluid buying cycle. Whatever you need, you can talk to me here (I promise I'm not as ecentric as this block of text lets on.).</br>
                </br>
                Contact: <strong>tono.nogueras@gmail.com</strong>
                </p>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

.about
{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top:100px;
display: block;
font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
width: 425px;
}

.aboutcontent {
display: none;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#about a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.aboutcontent').show();
   });
});
```

and note that your HTML is ***really*** invalid, missing closing elements just about everywhere.

Comment: This definitely did the job. I've got a lot to learn still it seems. Thanks!